# Architecture: Websockets sends message based on triggers from database

Tags: database, events, websocket, triggers, architecture

I was implementing WebSockets just for practice and I encountered an architectural problem.

It's nice to have WebSockets, but I cannot figure out a simple **scalable** scenario.

**Possible Scenario:**

Browser users start some computationally difficult task over the frontend. It goes over the API server, API puts the task to a queue, some other GPU server with celery pulls the task and starts working on it. Somewhere on the way, possibly, there is a database saving a state. So I would say API and celery server writes in the DB under particular task information about what's going on.

Now the important part. There is a WebSocket server connected to the browser client. It would be great that WebSockets are simplex and only sends messages to browser clients about the progress of the task (status, progress bar % and etc). The WebSocket is clever and doesn't need periodical polling, but manages to send data to the browser client based on events that are triggered (by API and celery). Obviously, the WebSocket server needs to listen to this task state (Redis or something, certainly not something at the same place as is WebSocket server). This means that in the WebSocket loop there must be a listener for this state. But this ends up back to WebSocket server polling this redis or something for seeing the state of the task -> this is certainly connection killer in case of a lot of users as there will be a lot of WebSocket connections polling same database.

**The question is then**: How to solve this in terms of architecture(no polling, WebSockets sends messages only on the state change of some value in some DB)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose that celery server also sends a task information to some queue. The WebSocket server would have to have a code responsible for reading from that queue and distributing that task information to its clients (WebSocket connections) that listen for that particular task information.